# I need to run my exe when user logs into windows, please tell me steps for this

Tags: windows, vb.net, exe, startup-folder

I have copied my exe to Startup folder its working fine on windows Restart but i need to run exe when computer is resumed from Hibernate or Sleep mode too..
Please help me with this !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: From Windows perspective there's nothing special about resuming from Hibernate or Sleep - everything just starts working again.

Comment: You can probably create a scheduled task, triggered on the resume event.

Comment: if user won't end that process, the exe file will resume after hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find an easier way your event log will  give you hints on hibernation and sleep mode. You can create a small app and run your exe when these event arrive.
https://superuser.com/questions/28567/at-what-time-did-my-windows-xp-machine-come-out-of-
hibernation